# Can a Dropbox folder be removed by people its been shared with?

Tags: dropbox, sharing

If someone shares a Dropbox folder, can the person it's shared with remove the files or will they remain on Dropbox for the person who shared them?

Answer (score 0):

No. You grant users read access to files. The have no ability to delete them.

Comment: Thanks for answering keltari ..I thought not but I needed assurance.

Comment: @user2998369 no problem. Be sure to vote and accept.

Answer (score 0):

A folder can be shared read-only or as a true shared folder, which all parties have read/write access to. Either party can add files to or delete files from a standard shared folder.